# Conditional expectation given two outcomes

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

The solution for the question$^1$ is $E(S_3|S_1(H)) = p^2(HHH) + pq(HHT) + qp(HTH) + q^2(HTT)$; but what is it to $E(S_3|S_1)$?

Probably shift one node up and then we have p^3 and q^3 but is then pq^2, qp^2?

1: [Stochastic Calculus For Finance: Conditional Expectation of Binomial Tree Model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006584/stochastic-calculus-for-finance-conditional-expectation-of-binomial-tree-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the notation of the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006584/stochastic-calculus-for-finance-conditional-expectation-of-binomial-tree-model):$$\mathbb E(S_3\mid S_1)=\mathbb E(S_3\mid S_1(\mathsf H))\,\mathbf 1_{S_1(\mathsf H)}+\mathbb E(S_3\mid S_1(\mathsf T))\,\mathbf 1_{S_1(\mathsf T)}$$

> The solution for the question$^1$ is $${\mathbb E(S_3\mid S_1(\mathsf H)) ~{= p^2S_3(\mathsf {HHH}) + pqS_3(\mathsf {HHT}) + qpS_3(\mathsf {HTH}) + q^2S_3(\mathsf {HTT})\\=32p^2+16pq+2q^2}}$$

Indeed.  The coefficients are the *conditional* probability for the string of three coin flips *when given* that it starts with one head showing.

Similarly the conditional expectation for the value of three coin flips when given the value of the first flip indicates that it is a tail, is going to have the same coefficients (since each subsequent coin flip is independent of the previous) and differ only by relevant the valuations:-

$${\mathbb E(S_3\mid S_1(\mathsf T)) ~{= p^2S_3(\mathsf {THH}) + pqS_3(\mathsf {THT}) + qpS_3(\mathsf {TTH}) + q^2S_3(\mathsf {TTT})\\=8p^2+4pq+0.50q^2}}$$

---

With the valuations taken from the diagram below, which indicates you start with $4$, double for each head showing, and halve for each tail. Ie: let $h$ be the count for heads in a string of length $h+t$, then the string has the value $2^{2+h-t}$.

[image]